# Turn on Windows Mobile hotspot without Internet or use Loopback adapter only

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, mobile-hotspot

I try to use Windows Mobile hotspot to connect technical device with my notebook. It's working, but only if the notebook has connection to Internet. I need to use this configuration without Internet too. Is it possible somehow to start Windows Mobile hotspot without Internet or having created Microsoft Virtual Loopback adapter?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can...

First create your loopback adapter. You can create a loopback adapter by opening device manager, click on your computer name at the top of the list, then go to action menu/add legacy hardware. From there click next, then Install the hardware that I manually select from a list, then select Network Adapters, then next, then select Microsoft on the left and Microsoft KM-TEST Loopback Adapter on the right, then next and next again.

Go to Control Panel/Network and Internet/Network and Sharing Center/Change adapter settings. Right click on network adapter you just created and rename it to Loopback.

Then you can run this PowerShell script to start the hotspot bound to the loopback adapter.

$profile = [Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation,Windows.Networking.Connectivity,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]::GetConnectionProfiles()  | where {$_.profilename -eq "loopback"}

$tether = [Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators.NetworkOperatorTetheringManager,Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]::CreateFromConnectionProfile($profile)

$tether.StartTetheringAsync()

You can make other changes by going to Mobile Hotspot in Settings, e.g. turn off power saving so the hotspot doesn't automatically disable itself if no client is connected.

Your hotspot(host) will have the IP address 192.168.137.1 and you will be able to access it by computer name if you make the firewall changes below.

All firewall rules still apply to this network, so access to your computer will be in the PUBLIC network. I have set the loopback adapter to private, and it works, but for some reason it always eventually sets itself back to public, presumably because the network can't be identified.

To access shares on the host:
Go to Control Panel/Network and Internet/Network and Sharing Center/select change advanced sharing settings on the left, then click Guest or Public and Turn on network discovery and turn on file and printer sharing.